# obj/Debug/android/bin/classes: file not found

Tags: java, android, mono, xamarin

I'm working in xamarin IDE and this error will not let me debug my project.
Does anyone know why this could be happening?
Below is the full error output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Tool exited with code: 1. Output: 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: obj/Debug/android/bin/classes: file not found
    at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
1 error; aborting
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently got this same exact exception message in my build. For me, the issue was resolved by closing the solution and manually deleting ALL of the following temp folders in the project:

> bin, obj, packages, components

Probably there's a more specific file somewhere in there that's misbehaving; but I haven't narrowed that down yet. It's also possible that the error message itself is simply somewhat generic, but if you see this exception it probably wouldn't hurt to clean those folders manually as a first diagnostic step.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your full project path does not contain non-ASCII characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing bin and obj folder worked for me.